# juju server relation hook files are not running?

Tags: server, juju

Hi This question based one this link.[How do I add a relationship between two charms to pass information between them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504482/how-do-i-add-a-relationship-between-two-charms-to-pass-information-between-them/504581#504581i) want to add relation to two charms.First one is server charm and other one is application charm.I have added two hooks file one for server charm and application charm.those are backend-relation-joined and server-relation-joined. In the yaml file i have add those relations as providers and require relations.But when i deploy charm it doesn't run the backend-relation-joined hook and server-relation-joined hook file.These are the only hook files are running.I want to know why my relation joined hooks are not running.

```
2014-08-01 05:09:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:494 ran "install" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:505 committing "install" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:520 committed "install" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:396 ModeContinue starting
2014-08-01 05:09:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:48 continuing after "install" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:396 ModeConfigChanged starting
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:480 running "config-changed" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:494 ran "config-changed" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:505 committing "config-changed" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:520 committed "config-changed" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:396 ModeContinue starting
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:48 continuing after "config-changed" hook
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:396 ModeStarting starting
2014-08-01 05:09:28 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:480 running "start" hook
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you related them by running `juju add-relation <service1> <service2>` ?

Or in the GUI by clicking the `Create relation` button.

You can read a lot more on creating relationships here https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-relations In fact your best bet would be to read the docs from start to finish, lots of great information in there.

Comment: Thanks it works.But after creating relationship how i get details like private IP and public ip from the relationship thanks.