# How to determine the IPs of other components while deploying a charm on nova-compute?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I am writing a custom charm that is installed on the nova-compute. D

uring the installation, I need to configure some OS files with the information of OS controller, cinder, neutron gateway etc.

How do I determine the IPs of these components? Are there any hooks available within the charm to do this? I prefer to write the charm in bash but Python is ok too.

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/504482/how-do-i-add-a-relationship-between-two-charms-to-pass-information-between-them

Answer (score 1):

If the units need to "know" about each other in some way (even if it's just knowing the IP address of each other), then they need to be related.

Please see the link that @Jorge Castro posted, as it is a great starting point:

- [How do I add a relationship between two charms to pass information between them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504482/)