# Charm Using RabbitMQ

Tags: juju, rabbitmq

Here is problem:

1) I have a RabbitMQ on Juju.

2) I have a charm which tries to use RabbitMQ, written in Java (I'll call it `myCharm`).

3) `myCharm` needs Hostname or IP address of RabbitMQ.

How can I find the IP address or hostname of RabbitMQ on my Juju?

Comment: Check out this question, if it doesn't answer your questions please edit your existing question with your specific question, thanks!: http://askubuntu.com/questions/504482/how-do-i-add-a-relationship-between-two-charms-to-pass-information-between-them/504581#504581

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure your charm can relate to rabbitmq-server using the `rabbitmq` relation. For examples of other charms that already do this, take a look at https://manage.jujucharms.com/interfaces/rabbitmq.

Once you do that, deploying both rabbitmq charm and your charm and running `juju add-relation rabbitmq mycharm` will trigger a relation hook inside your charm where you can use the `relation-get hostname` command to get the IP.

For a much more detailed explanation of how relations work, check the excellent link Jorge Castro provided in the comment above.