# What are all steps to setup juju charm relationship

Tags: juju

Assume i am creating a charm which is having a java class in it say Helloworld.java.
Now I want to compile and run this class by using jdk6 from a different charm.

Can somebody explain me what all changes I need to do.
Basically I am struggling in relationship creation hence want to get it clear.

In my original implementation, I have a deb package in my charm, this deb package needs jdk6 and hadoop preinstalled(install script checks the availability checking JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME in the PATH).

I am totally stuck on adding the relationship(in metadata.yaml and *-relation-*). I am not clear at all that how can I use java and hadoop from different charms.

Comment: You can try this, [How do I define a relationship?](http://askubuntu.com/a/504581/633029) Hope it will help you.

Comment: Iv'e gone through that, but still not clear with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the jdk installed via another charm you will need to create a subordinate charm (https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/authors-subordinate-services).
A subordinate charm operates in the same instance (container) as the charm he is subordinate for.

The metadata.yaml would look somewhat like this:

```
name: 
summary: 
maintainer: 
description: 
tags: [misc]
subordinate: true
requires:
  interface-name:
    interface: interface-name
series: ['trusty']
```

The following interfaces can be used for Java JDK and Hadoop:

- https://github.com/juju-solutions/interface-java
- https://github.com/juju-solutions/interface-hadoop-plugin

---

Small example:
Assuming you want the jdk from another charm I'll use the kafka charm as an example and use the jdk it installs.

metadata.yaml

```
name: layer-jdk-example
summary: <Fill in summary here>
maintainer: maintainer
description: |
  <Multi-line description here>
tags:
  - misc
subordinate: true
requires:
  kafka:
    interface: kafka
    scope: container
series: ['trusty']
```

layer.yaml

```
includes: ['layer:basic', 'interface:kafka']
```

reactive/layer-jdk-example.py

```
import os
from charms.reactive import when, when_not, set_state


@when_not('layer-jdk-example.installed')
def install_layer_jdk_example():    
    os.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
    # locate / download java file and compile
    # do stuff ... 
    set_state('layer-jdk-example.installed')
```

Build, deploy and add a relation to kafka. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know it sounds dumb but I couldn't write this. @user3499430, if you get time and can do me a favour then can you help me out personally?
otherwise my charm will remain single on this valentine :)
Thanks anyways.

Comment: Are you creating a layered charm?

Comment: Yes i am trying to create a layered one. I am actually referring apache-spark's charm, but that one is too complicated.

Comment: without layer design will also work for me. I have created an empty public github repo @ [link](https://github.com/userasr/juju.git)

Comment: Added a small example, I don't have time for more atm. Will check on it again later.

Comment: Thanks, now my charm can access java from the kafka charm.
same i am trying with hadoop-plugin charm but no success there.

Comment: Thanks @user3499430, now my charm can access java from the kafka charm.
same i am trying with hadoop-plugin charm but no success there.

layer.yaml is `includes: ['layer:basic', 'interface:hadoop-plugin']` and in metadata.yaml, i only changed the require module to hadoop-plugin

Comment: Pushed my charm @ [github](https://github.com/userasr/juju)

Comment: For hadoop it gets a bit trickier. Working with the interface that I linked you need to provide the relation in your metadata, not require it. The require part is done by the plugin charm (https://jujucharms.com/apache-hadoop-plugin/). This also means that your charm will not be subordinate for hadoop (the plugin is a subordinate).

Comment: My understanding was that i will just replace kafka to hadoop-plugin in metadata.yaml and that will work.
From doc i couldn't understand much about when to use`provides` or `requires`.

Comment: The interface README will clarify which to use.

Comment: apart from changing it to `provides` what other change will be required? after adding the relation, the hadoop-plugin status is still `waiting`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53736/discussion-between-asr-and-user3499430).